# Embedding from Rational Numbers to Ordered Field is Order Preserving

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, order-theory, ordered-fields

I am dealing with ordering of rings, so the definition I am using is:

**Order Preserving** - Let $R'$ and $R$ be ordered rings, and let $P'$, $P$ be their sets of positive elements respectively. Let $f : R'\to R$ be an embedding. We shall say that $f$ is order preserving if for every $x\in R'$ such that $x\in P'$ we have $f(x)\in P$. In other words, $f^{-1}(P)=P'$.

Now the question is: let $K$ be an ordered field and $f :  \mathbf{Q}\to K$ be the embedding (why 'the' not just 'an'?) of the rational numbers into K. Show that $f$ is necessarily order preserving.

Anyone have any ideas or solutions on this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "The" embedding because you _have_ to map $1$ to $1$, and the rest of the embedding follows from there.

Comment: Can you show that $f(1)\in P$?

Comment: @Chris Culter Yes, $f(1)$$\in$P because the ring homomorphism will map f(1) to 1, and P must contain the identity.

Comment: @P-S.D Okay, how about $f(2)$ and $f(1/2)$?

Comment: @Chris Culter As it is a homomorphism $f(2)$=$f(1)+f(1)$=$1+1=2$. Hence, f(x)=x where x is an integer. Also $f(1/2)$=$f(2)^{-1}$=$1/2$. Hence, $f(1/a)$=$f(a)^{-1}$=1/a.

Comment: Right, and are $f(n)\in P$ and $f(1/n)\in P$ for integers $n>0$? How about $f(m/n)$ for $m,n>0$?

Comment: @Chris Culter For integers $n$ greater than $0$, certainly $f(n)=n$$\in$P (an ordering of the rational numbers). And because $\mathbf{Q}$ and K are both fields, this embedding is necessarily a linear map, and therefore $f(m/n)=mf(1/n)=m(1/n)=m/n$, and so therefore $f(m/n)$ is in P for $m,n$ greater than $0$. Is this a complete proof?

Comment: @ChrisCulter I'm all done with the proof, I just don't understand why $f(1/n)=1/n$ must be in P.

Comment: @ChrisCulter never mind I found out myself. Thanks a lot for helping!